# Displaying the last post item of each category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails application and i have two models posts and category. Category has_many :posts and Post belongs_to :category. Now how can i display the last post item of each category. i.e retrieving the last post in each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view something like:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
 <p><%= category.posts.last %></p>
<% end %>
```

the example above will order the records by id but you might want to order the result by "created_at" field (in case you have it):

```
<%= category.posts.order('created_at desc').last %>
```

Comment: sorry, PHP in my mind... :)   It should be:  `@categories.each do |category|`

Comment: if you pass in category.post.last it outputs #<Post:0xec98ef0>  it doesn't give the list of posts

Comment: what view are you using to try this? What controller is calling that view? Oh, and put an 's' at the end of post(s)

Comment: i am using my root_path which is my welcome controller not my categories controller. i want the index view to display the last post of each category

Comment: You should do in your controller: @categories = Category.all

Comment: doing it you way works only in the show view ie viewing the last post of only one category at a time

Comment: have you defined the category_id column in the posts migration? Try executing in your rails console: Category.first.posts, and let's see if you get what you should

Comment: it returns the posts of that category

Comment: Your model setup is OK, then. Something is wrong in the way you retrieve all the categories from the database in the welcome controller, did put there: @categories = Category.all  ?

Comment: Let me get everything right: you have a welcome controller, wich has an index action, wich has inside `@categories = Category.all`. Also, you have the index view, which is in the views/welcome folder, and has inside the code i gave in the answer. Is all that right?